# Ellipse focus locus

Tags: geometry

What curvature properties ( intrinsic equation) does the locus of  focus of an rolling ellipse on outside of a fixed circle have? (When circle becomes larger and flat, the locus tends to a constant mean curvature  meridian of Delaunay unduloids) .General loci are required for perimeter ratios <1, =1, and >1 cases. Use of polar coordinates recommended, origin as circle center.

Comment: How is the ellipse rolling on a circle? is the ellipse on the inside or outside? is the circle rolling and the ellipse on top? More information is needed, I think.

Comment: Isn't circle always flat?

Comment: You may like : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483247/rolling-ellipses

Comment: Do ellipse and circle have equal perimeter? If not, what is the ratio between their perimeters?